# Linker problems with GLEW and CodeBlcks

Tags: opengl, linker, sdl, codeblocks, glew

I'm trying to get glew to work with Code::Blocks. I'm using OpenGL with SDL. From what I've read I'm having problems with  linking according to my errors.(see below) Here is how my linking in CB is setup

[image]

**Errors**

```
-------------- Build: Debug in ColdFusion ---------------

Linking executable: bin\Debug\ColdFusion.exe
Warning: .drectve `/DEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMT" /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES" ' unrecognized
lib\glew32s.lib(./static/release/glew.obj):(.text[__glewInit_GL_VERSION_1_2]+0x4): undefined reference to `_imp__wglGetProcAddress@4'
lib\glew32s.lib(./static/release/glew.obj):(.text[__glewInit_GL_VERSION_1_3]+0x4): undefined reference to `_imp__wglGetProcAddress@4'
lib\glew32s.lib(./static/release/glew.obj):(.text[__glewInit_GL_VERSION_1_4]+0x4): undefined reference to `_imp__wglGetProcAddress@4'
lib\glew32s.lib(./static/release/glew.obj):(.text[__glewInit_GL_VERSION_1_5]+0x4): undefined reference to `_imp__wglGetProcAddress@4'
lib\glew32s.lib(./static/release/glew.obj):(.text[__glewInit_GL_VERSION_2_0]+0x4): undefined reference to `_imp__wglGetProcAddress@4'
lib\glew32s.lib(./static/release/glew.obj):(.text[__glewInit_GL_VERSION_2_1]+0x4): more undefined references to `_imp__wglGetProcAddress@4' follow
lib\glew32s.lib(./static/release/glew.obj):(.text[_glewGetExtension@4]+0xa): undefined reference to `_imp__glGetString@4'
lib\glew32s.lib(./static/release/glew.obj):(.text[_glewContextInit@0]+0x4): undefined  reference to `_imp__glGetString@4'
lib\glew32s.lib(./static/release/glew.obj):(.text[__glewInit_WGL_3DL_stereo_control]+0x7): undefined reference to `_imp__wglGetProcAddress@4'
lib\glew32s.lib(./static/release/glew.obj):(.text[__glewInit_WGL_AMD_gpu_association]+0x4): undefined reference to `_imp__wglGetProcAddress@4'
lib\glew32s.lib(./static/release/glew.obj):(.text[__glewInit_WGL_ARB_buffer_region]+0x4): undefined reference to `_imp__wglGetProcAddress@4'
lib\glew32s.lib(./static/release/glew.obj):(.text[__glewInit_WGL_ARB_create_context]+0x7): undefined reference to `_imp__wglGetProcAddress@4'
lib\glew32s.lib(./static/release/glew.obj):(.text[__glewInit_WGL_ARB_extensions_string]+0x7): undefined reference to `_imp__wglGetProcAddress@4'
lib\glew32s.lib(./static/release/glew.obj):(.text[__glewInit_WGL_ARB_make_current_read]+0x4): more undefined references to `_imp__wglGetProcAddress@4' follow
lib\glew32s.lib(./static/release/glew.obj):(.text[_wglewGetExtension@4]+0x21): undefined reference to `_imp__wglGetCurrentDC@0'
lib\glew32s.lib(./static/release/glew.obj):(.text[_wglewContextInit@0]+0x4): undefined reference to `_imp__wglGetProcAddress@4'
lib\glew32s.lib(./static/release/glew.obj):(.text[_wglewContextInit@0]+0x3e): undefined reference to `_imp__wglGetCurrentDC@0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 5 seconds)
15 errors, 1 warnings
```

Answer (score 3):

While I don't know how Code::Blocks handles libraries and their order, I know that the order is important. You need to place the libraries that depend on something *before* the library it depends on.

So if one of the SDL libraries depend on function in the glew library, then the glew library should be *after* the SDL library in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've figured out that order matters, it's just finding the right order I'm having problems with.

Comment: My link order was: -lmingw32 -lglew32s -lOpenGL32 -lglu32 Since I had SDL2, it was: -lmingw32 -lglew32s -lOpenGL32 -lglu32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2